# Get variable from public class for two forms

Tags: c#, .net

I want to open a new form - AdminForm from my existing form. The new form asks for a password, which should be transfered to a variable in the MainForm.

For this I've created a class:

```
public class Decrypt
{    
    public static string AdminPass { get; set; }
}
```

I referenced the public class in the AdminForm and set a value in the AdminPass variable.

```
public Decrypt AdminPass { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtAdminPass.Text == "2017")
    {
        Decrypt.AdminPass = "yes";
        this.Close();
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect. Try again.");
    }
}
```

Finally, I'm trying to access the variable in my MainForm like this:

```
private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (AdminForm openForm = new AdminForm() { AdminPass = new Decrypt() })
    {
        if (openForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {    
            label23.Text = Decrypt.AdminPass;
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: the variable to Decrypt.AdminPass;

However. The variable seems to be assigned only in the `AdminForm`. So if I do `MessageBox.Show(Decrypt.AdminPass);` in the `AdminForm`, the `string 'Yes'` gets printed. But in `MainForm`, the `label23.Text` remains the same.

Any clues where I'm getting it wrong?

I understand this is a basic question, but I'm quite new to C#.

Comment: u r calling a non static property from a static method..Try making the property static( assuming they are in the same class)

Comment: Why not just use `Decrypt.AdminPass` when you get it?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan,agreed

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I did this. The code compiles, but I'm unable to retrieve the string value.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: You are confusing yourself with your naming of code elements.

Comment: "the label23.Text remains the same." - the same as what?

Comment: @Igor23 - label23 has initial value - "TextExample". The value should be replaced with "yes". As I'm assigning `label23.Text = Decrypt.AdminPass;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (txtAdminPass.Text == "2017")
{
    Decrypt.AdminPass = "yes";
    //this.Close();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;  // !!!
} 
else ...
```

Comment: That looks so obvious looking back. Thanks.